# OpenGL coordinate transformation

Tags: opengl

I have a window of size (475,574). When I use mouse Click event to get the position on screen
I get in range of (0-475,0-574). I am using  glOrthof(-1.5, +1.5, -1.5, +1.5, 4.0, 15.0)
so my question is how would I transform the point that I get through mouse event to a 3D openGL point.

eg- How would I transform (100,200) to  (-1.2,0.234,6)

Comment: `-1` : This question shows little to no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to convert between the two coordinate systems to turn screen coordinates into world coordinates.

```
//calculate ratio
widthRatio = 3.0 / width; // 3.0 = total width of viewport
heightRatio = 3.0 / height; // 3.0 = total height of viewport

worldX = (screenX * widthRatio) - 1.5; // subtract 1.5 (half of viewport width) to get origin
worldY = (screenY * heightRatio) - 1.5;
```

worldX and worldY should now be the appropriate point in your viewport.

Comment: Perhaps you could just make supplementary variable for viewport size, because I am sure a newbie would copy-and paste his own values into this. Let's encourage proper coding, even it's a pseudocode :)